# Expressing complex logic in case statements in dbt using a lookup table

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm reworking a good part of our Analytics Data Warehouse and am trying to build things out in a much more modular way. We've swapped to DBT vs an in house transformation tool and I'm trying to take advantage of the functionality it offers.

Previously, the way we classified our rental segments was in a series of CASE statements which evaluate a few fields. These are (sudocode)

```
CASE WHEN rental_rule_type <> monthly 
AND rental_length BETWEEN 6 AND 24
AND rental_day IN (0,1,2,3,4)
AND rental_starts IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
THEN weekday_daytime_rental
```

This obviously works. But it's ugly and hard to update. If we want to adjust this, we'll need to do so in the SQL rather than in a lookup table.

What I'd like to build is a simple lookup table that holds these values that can be adjusted at a later date to easily adjust how we classify these rentals, but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

My current thought is to layer these conditions into an excel file, load it into the warehouse with DBT and then join on these conditions, however I'm not sure if that would end up being cleaner logic or not. It would mean there are no hardcoded values in the code, but it would likely still result in a ton of ugly cases and joins.

I think there are some global variables I could define as well in DBT which may help with this?

Anyone approach something similar? Would love to hear some best practices.

Comment: I like the idea of a lookup table. Your case statements can be cleaned up if you structure it where each condition has both start and end conditions, and then use an inequality join to select the proper value.

Answer (score 3):

Love the question here and actually tconbeer's answer as well.
However, if you want an answer that "favor's readability over DRY-ness", there is an another appropriate middle ground here which is generally regarded as a dbt best-practice: model defined [sets](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros/#set-variables-at-the-top-of-a-model).

Example:

```
{% set rental_rule_type = ["bank_transfer"] %}
{% set rental_length_low = ["6"] %}
{% set rental_length_high = ["24"] %}
{% set rental_days = ["0","1","2","3","4"] %}
{% set rental_starts = ["5","6","7","8","9","10","11"] %}



with some_cte as (
  select * from {{ ref('some_source') }}
)
 select *,
CASE    
        WHEN rental_rule_type <> {{rental_rule_type}}
        AND rental_length BETWEEN {{rental_length_low}} AND {{rental_length_high}}
        AND rental_day IN (
            {% for rental_day in rental_days %}
            {{rental_day}} {%- if not loop.last -%}, {%- endif -%}
            {% endfor %}
        )
        AND rental_starts IN (
            {% for rental_start in rental_starts %}
            {{rental_start}} {%- if not loop.last -%}, {%- endif -%}
            {% endfor %}
        )
THEN weekday_daytime_rental
from some_cte
```

Example 2 (equivalent but cleaner as suggested in comment below):

```
{% set rental_rule_type = ["bank_transfer"] %}
{% set rental_length_low = ["6"] %}
{% set rental_length_high = ["24"] %}
{% set rental_days = ["0","1","2","3","4"] %}
{% set rental_starts = ["5","6","7","8","9","10","11"] %}



with some_cte as (
  select * from {{ ref('some_source') }}
)
 select *,
CASE    
        WHEN rental_rule_type <> {{rental_rule_type}}
        AND rental_length BETWEEN {{rental_length_low}} AND {{rental_length_high}}
        AND rental_day IN ( {{ rental_days | join(", ") }} )
        AND rental_starts IN (  {{ rental_starts | join(", ") }} )
THEN weekday_daytime_rental
from some_cte
```

In this format, all the logic stays accessible to someone who is reading the model but also makes changing the logic much more accessible since it contains all the variables to a single location.

Also, much easier to see that variables / macros are in play here at a quick glance of the model vs if your case statement is buried deep in a chain of CTEs or a more complex select statement after some CTEs.

**warning**
I haven't compiled this so I'm not 100% it will be successful as-is. Should get you started though if you go in this direction.

Comment: I do this too! I recommend using the join filter to turn a python list into a string, though. Your for loops can be replaced with {{ rental_days | join(“, “) }}

Comment: @tconbeer +1 thats definitely a great way to do it if its a simple join. Once in a while  I need to throw double quotes in on the item itself (like a column name with spaces) but really like that simple version! (going to add as edit to answer)

Comment: Wonderful - thank you so much! Unfortunately I haven't had a ton of time this week to work through it, so will give it a whirl this weekend or early next week. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what you describe, and I've generally regretted it.

Logic really should be expressed as code, not data. It should be source-controlled, reviewable, and support multiple environments (dev and prod).

Seed files (with dbt seed) are kind-of data, and kind-of code, since they get checked into source control alongside the code. This at least solves the multiple environments problem, but it makes code review extremely difficult.

I'd recommend doing what software engineers do -- encapsulate the logic into easily-understandable and easily-testable components, and then compose those components in your model. Macros work pretty well for this.

For example, your case statement above could become a macro called `is_weekday_daytime_rental()`:

```sql
{% macro is_weekday_daytime_rental(rental_rule_type, rental_legnth, rental_day, rental_starts) %}
CASE 
  WHEN rental_rule_type <> monthly 
    AND rental_length BETWEEN 6 AND 24
    AND rental_day IN (0,1,2,3,4)
    AND rental_starts IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
  THEN true
  ELSE false
END
{% endmacro %}
```

then you could call that macro in your model, like:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN
        {{ is_weekly_daytime_rental(
            rental_rule_type,
            rental_legnth,
            rental_day,
            rental_starts
        ) }} 
    THEN weekday_daytime_rental
    WHEN ...
```

But let's do better. Assuming you're also going to have `is_weekend_daytime_rental`, then each of those component bits of logic should be its own macro that you can reuse:

```sql
{% macro is_weekday_daytime_rental(rental_rule_type, rental_legnth, rental_day, rental_starts) %}
CASE 
  WHEN {{ is_daily_rental(rental_rule_type, rental_length) }}
    AND {{ is_weekday(rental_day) }}
    AND {{ is_daytime(rental_starts) }}
  THEN true
  ELSE false
END
{% endmacro %}
```

where each component looks like:

```sql
{% macro is_weekday(day_number) %}
CASE
    WHEN day_number IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    THEN true
    ELSE false
END
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I'm finally implementing this... (joys of being in 100000 meetings a day and DE telling you not to work after hours with a new tool XD).

QQ - why does your final macro end with endif, vs endmacro?

Comment: just a typo! Good catch. Answer updated